# Proving a language is not regular with pumping lemma

Tags: automata, pumping-lemma

I'm having a little bit of an issue with a pumping lemma problem. I've successfully completely all my other problems but this is the last one and I'm a little confused I must say. If anyone can help me out, it'd be much appreciated.

\begin{equation} 
A = \{a^n b^m c^l    \mid      n\leq m  \vee  m\leq l\}
\end{equation}

Comment: take $a^nb^n$ (no $c$'s) and pump up the $a$'s.

Comment: @RanG., that doesn't belong to the language. But $a^N b^N c^N$ does, take $N$ as the pumping lemma's constant, you can pump up the $a$.

Comment: @vonbrand: It does, since $n\leq n \vee n \leq 0$ is true.

Comment: @frafl, no coffee yet (misread $\wedge$ for $\vee$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand a little on Ran G.'s comment, given a pumping length of $p$, we can take the string $s=a^{p}b^{p} \in A$, then splitting into $s=xyz$, the $y$ section (the part that can be pumped) must be all $a$s, so pumping up leaves us with a string $s'=a^{p+k}b^{p} \notin A$.

Comment: My philosophy is to only provide hints to exercises.